# Help identify parasitic plant on oak seedling

Tags: species-identification, botany, parasitism

See pictures below. I found five of them on a patch of oak seedlings in northern Turkey yesterday, they are about 2 centimeters in diameter and smell like grass.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Five months later:
[image: 4]

I tried PlantNet and Google Lens before asking but nothing came up.

Comment: I've asked several botanists from North Caucasus, none of them know. Considering that it's green, it must be hemiparasite, like Viscum.

Comment: I wonder if these are galls formed by an insect. That may be who made the hole in the bottom in the third photo.

Comment: I second @Darlingtonia's comment. If you add your photo to iNaturalist, there is a user there, Megachiele (I don't know the name exactly), that is really good at galls. I've never seen a gall like that before. Really cool.

Comment: @JohnPolo Thank you both, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think these are galls produced by a wasp in the genus *Andricus*.

Here are some produced by [*A. polyceras*](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/92898128):
[image: Three Andricus polyceras galls on a branch tip. ©iNaturalist user alexcm, 2021, CC-BY-NC]

However, there are many species in this genus so more detail would be needed to narrow it down.

Comment: This looks very much like it, thanks. What more detail would you like me to provide?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this group, but a positive ID might require dissecting the galls, or capturing the wasps that emerge for inspection. The other most similar species I saw was _A. quercustozae_, but most of the photos showed much more bulbous galls. I didn't see any with the really narrow bases that your photos show.

Comment: The oldest relatives of these found in amber are from about 50 million years ago. They inject up to 70 active mutagens and viroids that hey use to control hosts.

Comment: Couldn't find any more galls to dissect. I'll go ahead and accept your answer, thanks again.